# How can I maintain my settings when switching Wordpress themes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on developing a series of Wordpress themes. These themes all need to have custom theme options, and they will all have custom theme options pages. However, some themes have options that are not used in other themes.

When I switch themes, customize the theme options on the new theme, and save the options, I notice that all the options that are not used by that theme are lost, and when switching back, have to be reset. Is there a way to make sure that those options stay in the database, even if they aren't being used by the current active theme?

Comment: If you write your theme settings into the wp_options table they should stay there. I don´t think that table gets purged automatically.

Comment: Site settings (via `wp_options`) are maintained regardless of theme. Perhaps the new theme is not using the same option names as the old one did. However, if they are using the same option names on the new theme as the old one, and you save options on the new theme, then those options will also reflect when you switch back to the old theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several functions for you to maintain your options for your theme.

When a theme is activated, then there are a hook, called `after_switch_theme`.

The best way, if you create an array, where the default option keys/values are.

So create an array like this:

```
$theme_default_options = array (
    //.....
);
```

So you can use to set up an option:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'theme_setup_function');
```

If you want to remove your options, or manipulate the database, when you switch the old theme, you can use the `switch_theme`. This happens on deactivation:

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'theme_deactivation_function');
```

There are 3 more funtion for you to manipulate options:

```
add_option($option, $value);
update_option($option, $value);
delete_option($option);
```

And in any of the switch function, you can use a foreach loop on your default option array.

Use a unique name for all option for all theme. For example, for theme `pingpong`, use a prefix like `pingpong_homepage`.